# Display daily and weekly data on AmChart

Tags: javascript, amcharts, candlestick-chart

Hello fellow human beings

I've been looking through the net and the AmChart docs, and I can't find a good solution to this.
I want to display daily candlestick data, and under that, display the corresponding weekly candlestick data.

I can get it to work, but it doesn't look right.
As there are less weekly candles, I want them to take up more horizontal space, or something similar.

I found some useful properties, like scale, but that scales both horizontal and vertical.

Does anyone have any tips or an elegant solution for displaying both daily and weekly candlesticks underneath one another?

Here is some code that I've been fiddling with.

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
//chart.paddingRight = 10;

chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = "vertical"; // stacks charts vertically

chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true; // no gaps inbetween candles

// base granularity for the data
dateAxis.baseInterval =
{
    timeUnit: 'day',
    count: 1
};

// base granularity for the grid lines
dateAxis.gridIntervals.setAll([
    { timeUnit: 'week' , count: 1 },
    { timeUnit: 'week' , count: 5 }
]);

dateAxis.paddingRight = '36px'; // creates a little space on the right of the data
dateAxis.endLocation = 1; // creates a little space on the right of the data

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.height = am4core.percent(50);
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.CandlestickSeries());

series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "close";
series.dataFields.openValueY = "open";
series.dataFields.lowValueY = "low";
series.dataFields.highValueY = "high";
series.xAxis = dateAxis;
series.yAxis = valueAxis;
series.simplifiedProcessing = true;
series.clustered = false;



var dateAxis2 = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis2.skipEmptyPeriods = true; // no gaps inbetween candles

// base granularity for the data
dateAxis2.baseInterval =
{
    timeUnit: 'week',
    count: 1
};

// base granularity for the grid lines
dateAxis2.gridIntervals.setAll([
    { timeUnit: 'week' , count: 1 },
    { timeUnit: 'week' , count: 5 }
]);

dateAxis2.paddingRight = '0px'; // creates a little space on the right of the data
dateAxis2.endLocation = 1; // creates a little space on the right of the data

var valueAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis2.height = am4core.percent(50);
valueAxis2.marginTop = '40px';
valueAxis2.tooltip.disabled = true;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.CandlestickSeries());
series2.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series2.dataFields.valueY = "close2";
series2.dataFields.openValueY = "open2";
series2.dataFields.lowValueY = "low2";
series2.dataFields.highValueY = "high2";
series2.xAxis = dateAxis2;
series2.yAxis = valueAxis2;
series2.simplifiedProcessing = true;
series2.clustered = false;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

chart.data = [ {
    "date": "2019-12-30",
    "open": "136.65",
    "high": "136.96",
    "low": "134.15",
    "close": "136.49",
    "open2": "136.65",
    "high2": "137.24",
    "low2": "134.15",
    "close2": "135.03"
  }, {
    "date": "2019-12-31", "open": "135.26", "high": "135.95", "low": "131.50", "close": "131.85"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-02", "open": "132.90", "high": "135.27", "low": "128.30", "close": "135.25"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-03", "open": "134.94", "high": "137.24", "low": "132.63", "close": "135.03"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-06",
    "open": "136.76",
    "high": "136.86",
    "low": "132.00",
    "close": "134.01",
    "open2": "136.76",
    "high2": "136.86",
    "low2": "125.09",
    "close2": "124.03"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-07", "open": "131.11", "high": "133.00", "low": "125.09", "close": "126.39"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-08", "open": "123.12", "high": "127.75", "low": "120.30", "close": "125.00"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-09", "open": "128.32", "high": "129.35", "low": "126.50", "close": "127.79"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-10", "open": "128.29", "high": "128.30", "low": "123.71", "close": "124.03"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-13",
    "open": "122.74",
    "high": "124.86",
    "low": "119.65",
    "close": "119.90",
    "open2": "122.74",
    "high2": "128.96",
    "low2": "111.62",
    "close2": "127.57"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-14", "open": "117.01", "high": "118.50", "low": "111.62", "close": "117.05"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-15", "open": "122.01", "high": "123.50", "low": "119.82", "close": "122.06"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-16", "open": "123.96", "high": "124.50", "low": "120.50", "close": "122.22"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-17", "open": "122.21", "high": "128.96", "low": "121.00", "close": "127.57"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-20",
    "open": "131.22",
    "high": "132.75",
    "low": "130.33",
    "close": "132.51",
    "open2": "131.22",
    "high2": "135.37",
    "low2": "126.63",
    "close2": "126.82"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-21", "open": "133.09", "high": "133.34", "low": "129.76", "close": "131.07"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-22", "open": "130.53", "high": "135.37", "low": "129.81", "close": "135.30"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-23", "open": "133.39", "high": "134.66", "low": "132.10", "close": "132.25"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-24", "open": "130.99", "high": "132.41", "low": "126.63", "close": "126.82"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-27",
    "open": "129.88",
    "high": "134.18",
    "low": "129.54",
    "close": "134.08",
    "open2": "129.88",
    "high2": "145.84",
    "low2": "129.54",
    "close2": "136.76"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-28", "open": "132.67", "high": "138.25", "low": "132.30", "close": "136.25"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-02-29", "open": "139.49", "high": "139.65", "low": "137.41", "close": "138.48"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-30", "open": "139.94", "high": "145.73", "low": "139.84", "close": "144.16"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-01-31", "open": "144.97", "high": "145.84", "low": "136.10", "close": "136.76"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-02-03",
    "open": "135.56",
    "high": "137.57",
    "low": "132.71",
    "close": "135.01",
    "open2": "135.56",
    "high2": "139.40",
    "low2": "130.00",
    "close2": "136.85"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-02-04", "open": "132.01", "high": "132.30", "low": "130.00", "close": "131.77"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-02-05", "open": "136.99", "high": "138.04", "low": "133.95", "close": "136.71"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-02-06", "open": "137.90", "high": "138.30", "low": "133.75", "close": "135.49"
  }, {
    "date": "2020-02-07", "open": "135.99", "high": "139.40", "low": "135.75", "close": "136.85"
  }];
}); // end am4core.ready()
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 50%; height: 500px; background-color: #FFFFFF;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good news everyone... I have made some progress. It's not perfect. I'm still looking for more suggestions. I've edited the code snippet from above. It seems to work better when there is more data. I have a larger example on my laptop, but that's difficult to put onto here. Does anybody else have any other useful suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best solution.
If anybody out there has a better solution, let me know.

You can add multiple date axes to the chart.
Then when you add a series, you specify the id of both the x and y axis.

So I added a date axis for the daily candle, and a date axis for the weekly candles.
They don't line up 100%, but it's close.
My chart has 400 daily candles, and the equivalent number of weekly candles, and it seems the bigger the charts get, the closer it looks to all lining up.
I also added a monthly chart, and it's not bad.

What I also did was add slightly different padding right on the chart, and that got them even closer

I removed all the labeling from the date axes to avoid any confusion.

That's the best solution that I could come up with.